# Trying to retain only non missing values (if any) for a particular variable(condition)

Tags: sas

my data is something like this

```
testA       testB       testC
XYZ          1          
XYZ          2           ABC
XYZ          3
XYZ          4           BCA
XYZ          5
ZYX          2
ZYX          3           LMN
ZYX          4
ZYX          5
YZX          1
YZX          2
```

For every unique value(first.testA) I would like to pick up a non missing value of test C with the smallest value of testB.But if there are no non missing values.I just want it to have the first line for that combination.In other words I want my end result to look like this

```
XYZ          2           ABC
ZYX          3           LMN
YZX          1
```

I did get what I want using datastep and macro programming but its very convuluted and tedious since I have numerous variables for which I want to do this.I would like to know if there is an easier way

```
dataset test001;

 proc sort data=test001;    by testA testB testC;    run;
 proc sort data=test001 nodupkey ;  by testA;  run;

data test002;
set test001;
if missing(testC) then output missing001;  
run;

data test003;  
merge test001    
  missing001;  
by testA;  
run;  

proc sort data=test001;  by testA testB testC;  run;  
proc sort data=test001 nodupkey ;  by testA;  run;
```

Comment: If you already have working code, consider taking this question, with your code, over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The whole point of that site is to take working code and make it better. If you don't do that, you should add your code here as well. It's hard to help you improve your code without seeing it.

Comment: I wouldn't post something like this on Code Review; for one, I don't know that there's anyone over there that programs in SAS, but for two, I wouldn't consider this "working code" - this is really "how do you do this".  SAS often has things that "work" but aren't really good solutions; that should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: But for sure - mikila, if you want help, you need to improve your question.  Get the formatting right (i'll help with that, but look at what I do for the future - "CTRL-K" is your friend), and more importantly post either the actual code you used or an example that sufficiently describes how you approached this.  Not only does it give others a starting point for helping you, but it shows what you know how to do - meaning you can get an appropriate answer for your skill level, not something way over your head that you won't understand nor something overly simple.

Comment: my approach was to use proc sorts , merges to get rid of the other values

Comment: Go ahead and include an example that works on your example data - the merges may well be one of the things I was thinking of suggesting.  Include it in your question as an edit.

Comment: You should probably give a better example of what you want with multiple variables, as the ansewr may be improved when you explain that.  There's no particular reason to have to 'consolidate' back to one dataset - in theory you should be able to do this with two or more variables directly into one dataset.  However, you will have to explain exactly what you mean, and exactly what happens if you have collisions (if it matters) (ie, if you have one row that is the 'chosen' row for two different conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, what you need is effectively two passes through the data: one to identify id-groups (testA groups) that have a testC row that's useful, and one to grab the first row of those that don't.

Two ways immediately present themselves to me, in the data step.  PROC SQL could also pretty easily achieve this if you are more comfortable in that.

The simplest method is simply to create a dataset of those records who never have a testC record, and merge that back to the main dataset.  This seems close to what you were doing, but a bit faster this way.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by testa testb;
run;

data have_notestC;
  set have;
  by testA;
  if first.testA then testCcount = 0;        *for each testA group reinitialize the counter;
  if not missing(testC) then testCcount+1;   *if you see a testC then update counter;
  if last.testA and testCcount=0 then output;*if counter=0 then you never hit testC;
run;

data want;
  merge have have_notestC(in=_ntc);
  by testA;
  if first.testA then testCcount=0;            *reinitialize counter;
  if _ntc and first.testA then output;         *if it was a _ntc record then it has no testC;
  else if _ntc then delete;                    *if not first.testA and _ntc then uninteresting;
  else if testCcount = 0 and not missing(testC) then do;
    testCcount+1;                              *if testCcount=0 and testC is present then you want it;
    output;
  end;
                                               *otherwise ignore;
run;
```

A more efficient but more difficult method is the double DoW loop.  It mirrors the merge solution but does it inside one datastep.  It's more efficient because the two passes through the data are done in one read from disk, assuming your BY group size is small enough - and it can be done without sorting, if the values are all 'together' but not necessarily in alphabetic order (like your data is above - YZX is after ZYX, but all of the rows for each testA value are consecutive.)

```
data want;
  testCcount=0;
  hasOutput=0;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.testA);
    set have;
    by testA notsorted;
    if not missing(testC) then testCcount=1;
  end;
  do _n_= 1 by 1 until (last.testA);
    set have;
    by testA notsorted;
    if first.testA and testCcount=0 then output;
    else if testCcount=0 then delete;
    else if hasOutput=0 and not missing(testC) then do;
      output;
      hasOutput=1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Neither of these necessarily make it super easy to deal with things if you have many variables that you're working with, although the DoW loop version could be run for multiple variables (but not easily as a macro, because you need to change things in multiple places for each variable you're adding).  It's not totally clear to me how you would do this for 'numerous variables' anyway (since output is a row-based thing) but it could be adapted certainly depending on the details.